# Deploying CraftCMS to Digital Ocean

Tags: entries, database, deployment

Currently I'm having an issue deploying to Digital Ocean and would love some advice, i've followed numerous tutorials but they seem to just drop off half way through the process so just need some clarity on this. I've broke down what I've done below:

- Developed my CraftCMS site in localhost using MAMP.
- Committed everything to Github apart from **db.php**
- Created a droplet with LAMP
- Setup my database names so it corresponds with my localhost
- Setup my database user
- Created a deploybot setup which contains my     db.php file
- Deployed the application using deploy bot which deploys my latest
  push in the git repo.

Am I supposed to be reinstalling CraftCMS on the droplet and upload my localhost database after these steps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to read through the following articles:

https://nystudio107.com/blog/multi-environment-config-for-craft-cms

https://nystudio107.com/blog/database-asset-syncing-between-environments-in-craft-cms

About reinstalling craft on your droplet and uploading the local database:

the craft install i used in my local dev environment will be pushed onto the droplet, like this i can assure that it doesn't differ in any of the enviornments. About syncing the database read through the articles it will clear things up. In general all of the articles in nystudios blog are more than helpful. i hope it helped at least a bit.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6BhLZFslRw install CraftCMS directly on DigitalOcean Droplet.